# Select2 keep loading after filter YII2

Tags: gridview, yii2, jquery-select2

thank for reading. I have some problem with select2 - filter gridview Yii2:

Yii2 render select2 when i load page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxXKI.png)

so it worked, data was filled, but select2 keep display loading icon:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go6tC.png)

here is my code, select2 in column "name"

```
<?=GridView::widget([
        'id'=>'crud-datatable',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'pjax'=>true,
        'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => ['enablePushState' => false]],
        'summary' => 'Từ {begin} đến {end}/ Tổng {totalCount} bản ghi',
        'columns' => array(
            [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                'width' => '20px',
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
                'width' => '30px',
            ],
            [
                'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
                'attribute'=>'name',
                'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'text-align:center'],
                'filter'=>\kartik\select2\Select2::widget([
                    'model' => $searchModel,
                    'attribute' => 'name',
                    'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\Catnew::find()->all(), 'name', 'name'),
                    'theme' => \kartik\select2\Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
                    'hideSearch' => false,
                    'options' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Search for name',
                    ]
                ])
            ],
            [
                'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
                'attribute'=>'position',
            ],
            [
                'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
                'attribute'=>'active',
            ],
            [
                'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
                'attribute'=>'home',
            ],
            [
                'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
                'attribute'=>'parent',
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
                'dropdown' => false,
                'vAlign'=>'middle',
                'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                    return Url::to([$action,'id'=>$key]);
                },
                'viewOptions'=>['role'=>'modal-remote','title'=>'View','data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
                'updateOptions'=>['role'=>'modal-remote','title'=>'Update', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
                'deleteOptions'=>['role'=>'modal-remote','title'=>'Delete',
                    'data-confirm'=>false, 'data-method'=>false,
                    'data-request-method'=>'post',
                    'data-toggle'=>'tooltip',
                    'data-confirm-title'=>'Are you sure?',
                    'data-confirm-message'=>'Are you sure want to delete this item'],
            ],

        ),
        'toolbar'=> [
            ['content'=>
                Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>', ['create'],
                ['role'=>'modal-remote','title'=> 'Create new Catnews','class'=>'btn btn-default']).
                Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>', [''],
                ['data-pjax'=>1, 'class'=>'btn btn-default', 'title'=>'Reset Grid']).
                '{toggleData}'.
                '{export}'
            ],
        ],          
        'striped' => true,
        'condensed' => true,
        'responsive' => true,          
        'panel' => [
            'type' => 'primary', 
            'heading' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Catnews listing',
            'before'=>'<em>* Resize table columns just like a spreadsheet by dragging the column edges.</em>',
            'after'=>BulkButtonWidget::widget([
                        'buttons'=>Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>&nbsp; Delete All',
                            ["bulkdelete"] ,
                            [
                                "class"=>"btn btn-danger btn-xs",
                                'role'=>'modal-remote-bulk',
                                'data-confirm'=>false, 'data-method'=>false,
                                'data-request-method'=>'post',
                                'data-confirm-title'=>'Are you sure?',
                                'data-confirm-message'=>'Are you sure want to delete this item'
                            ]),
                    ]).                        
                    '<div class="clearfix"></div>',
        ]
    ])?>
```

hope your help :)

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
 [
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'value' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\Catnew::find()->all(), 'name', 'name'), 
    'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
    'filter' =>\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\Catnew::find()->all(), 'name', 'name'),
    'filterWidgetOptions' => [
        'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
    ],
    'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => '...'],
    'format' => 'raw'
 ],
```

Comment: I am using grid view and in it I have placed `[
                            'attribute' => 'Sub_Division_Name',
                        
                        'filter' => Select2::widget([
        'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\SurveyHescoSubdivision::find()->all(),'id','name'),
        'name' => 'Sub_Division_Name',
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Sub Division Name',
        ],
        'theme' => Select2::THEME_DEFAULT,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
        ],
    ]),

                    ],`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this is what I did and fixed the issue;
Just check and make sure you have not enabled pjax twice in your code. 
Check at the beginning of the grid view if there is something like the code below

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
```

If you find it then remove that one and this

```
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Then you should enable pjax in the Kartik Gridview like so

```
'pjax' => true,
```

Answer (score -1):

'pjax'=>**true** change to **false**
well done